# Final Cut Pro is distorting my music at the very end

Tags: audio, final-cut-pro

I have a problem and I can't find any fix. When I import songs into FCP it sometimes distorts them in the end. But the problem is that they sound fine outside of FCP, and I have paid for them, so it's the best quality it can get. I will link an example...

Comment: Welcome! What version of FCP? What codec and parameters are the source files? What are the differences between songs that import ok and songs that import with a problem? Is the problem at the end of the source file, edit, or sequence? What player did you use to confirm that the source files are fine? What else have you tried doing to correct the problem?

Comment: @MichaelLiebman It's 10.3.4. "What codec and parameters are the source files?" I don't really understand these words but it's mp3 if that's any help... The difference is only the ending. I just dubbelclicked on the mp3 file, which opened in itunes, to play the sound and the ending was then fine. I have tried by replacing it with the same sound again, but nothing.